# HOG Detection : Webcam unable to grab new frame

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have the following code to get a video feed from a network cam and subsequently perform a HOG detection.

However, when i add the HOG detection code  , the code is only able to grab the first image upon running and it doesnt refresh  on subsequent iteration. I have checked, using breakpoint, that the program is continuously running.

Please advise. Thank you.

```
void doDetection(void){

    VideoCapture cap("http://user:password@10.0.0.1/mjpg/video.mjpg");

    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return;

    HOGDescriptor hog;

    hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

    while (true)
    {
        Mat img, mono_img;

        bool status = cap.read(img);

        if (status == false) break;

        vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;

        cvtColor(img, mono_img, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        equalizeHist(mono_img, mono_img);

        // this is the problem statement , when removed this program refresh fine
        hog.detectMultiScale(mono_img, found, 0, Size(8, 8), Size(50, 50), 1.05, 2);



        imshow("Show", img);

        if (waitKey(20) >= 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: HOG usually takes ages. try to increase the scaling from 1.05 to 1.5

Comment: @berak Hi i have tried that and it doesn't solve the problem. I have used breakpoint to check that the program is running smoothly (ie not stuck at a certain line).

Comment: again, try to speed it up: put a backgroundseparator in front of it, apply hog only on the moving parts. also, there's a gpu hog version

Comment: Probably your video stream gets out of snyc or sth? Can you copy the image and use hog in a separate thread or try hog on a (small) sub image for testing?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to happen even when you pause the execution of the code for a little while.
In my case  MJPEG OVERREAD would appear in the console, after which no more images would get grabbed from the stream, but the stream would still be `open´

I build this little check around this problem which resets the capture. just place this in your WHILE

```
    if (cap.isOpened())
    {
        cap.read(img);

        if (img.rows == 0)
        {
            cap.release();
            cap.open("");//Insert own url
            cap.read(img);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cap.open(""); //Insert own url
        cap.read(img);
    }
```

if this "solves" the problem by keeping you app running, you should capture the frames on a separate thread to prevent the stream from dying like this.
If this does not "solve" the problem, I'm not sure what else could be wrong